# How to define a C macro expression?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

how does one define a macro expression in C, whose arguments are also expressions?

The problem I am tackling is how to write an expression `MAX(X,Y)` that takes in the expressions `X` and `Y` (such as `x++` or `x+2`) and returns the maximum of the two. This expression should be defined in as a preprocessor macro.

Answer from a related post:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

and I am aware of the risks involved with `x++` in a macro (can be evaluated twice).

Kind regards

Comment: Expressions like `x+2` which have no side effects are fine to use in a macro. But an expression like `x++` should not be passed to a macro, unless you know for a fact that the expression will only be evaluated once. Which is why you're better off just writing a `max` function and let the compiler inline it.

Comment: [What are expressions with side effects and why should they be not passed to a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284073/what-are-expressions-with-side-effects-and-why-should-they-be-not-passed-to-a-ma)

Comment: I am aware of the issues with macros and why they should be avoided, it's just a specific practice problem that involves macro expressions that I came along. Thanks for the link, the solutions there answers my question :D

Comment: Cannot be done... Even if your macro redirects to a function, `x` & `y` may not match the datatypes of the function... `char` is one byte, and `long long` quite a few more... Even `memcmp()` won't work without knowing the size of the datatypes involved.. Heaven help you if you want to determine MAX( 42, 37.53 )...

Comment: With pure standard C you could write it as `#define MAX(a,b) (parse(#a) > parse(#b) ? (a) : (b) )`. Incredibly inefficient but only executes each expression once.

Comment: What's `parse`?

Comment: @Armali Some custom expression parser which you'd have to write yourself... as I said, incredibly inefficient. The correct solution is to write a function.

Comment: Many macro problems can be solved by using a function instead. A function call will only evaluate the parameters once.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with GCC by using a specific expression construct, see: [Statements and Declarations in Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Here is an example:

```
#define INTMAX(A, B) ({ int _a = (A), _b = (B) ; _a > _b ? _a : _b ; })
```

You can use [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) instead of `int` if you don't know the type of arguments.

Comment: There's no indication of the OP using gcc, so this answer is kind of off-topic.

Comment: @Lundin There's no indication of the OP sticking with another compiler despite gcc solving their problem.

Comment: SO doesn't work like that. You can't go post an answer in C++ either, unless the OP specifically mentioned using it. Also as it happens, excessive use of gcc non-standard extensions has turned into a pox and shouldn't be encouraged.